# Connection between Sharepoint server and Access

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint, server

Does anyone know how to set up the connection beetween Sharepoint server and MS Access?
The main idea is so to see all the changes of data manipulation with Access' database in  Sharepoint. I've no found any solving of this issue so far.

Answer (score 0):

You could build and publish an Access database to SharePoint, please refer to this aricle for more: 
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/build-and-publish-an-access-database-to-sharepoint-e68bf007-410c-43b2-bf21-322ddbcf5411

Besides, this article would be helpful to you:

[Import, link, or move data to SharePoint](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/import-link-or-move-data-to-sharepoint-65bf7b03-74bf-445c-959a-24b7a401ddee)